# git implanting a branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have cloned a git repo locally. I have made a number of commits to master branch and *not* pushed into remote. In the meantime, others have added to the master of remote. Now I want to keep my commits on remote repo but in a branch that starts at the commit that I initially cloned from. The main reason is to keep the history of my commits, yet not to merge with master. Thanks in advance for any useful ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your remote is `origin` and your local branch is `master` and you'd like to push to `new_branch`:

```
git push origin master:new_branch
```

Comment: Wow, super! Does this create the new branch by name new_branch and also at the point I initially did my clone? If so, when I pull from remote next, it will pull the whole repo with my new branch at right place?

Comment: If `new_branch` does not already exist, it will be created. The current state of your `master` will be pushed to `new_branch`, so the commit tree will remain as-is. If you then wanted to pull the current `origin/master` without merging your commits, you would run `git fetch origin`, `git reset --hard origin/master` (while on `master`) and then `git pull`. Make sure you've successfully pushed `new_branch` before doing so as this will remove all of your commits from master leaving them only in `new_branch`. If you wanted to merge or rebase your commits, skip the reset.

Answer (score 1):

cjc343's answer, while technically correct, feels incomplete to me.  I'd suggest making a local branch for your work and then pushing it.  And that way master can track origin/master, and trust me, life is easier when you're doing this.

Assuming you're at HEAD, and your master is still several commits beyond your initial clone point...

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git push origin new_branch
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This 1) makes a new local branch, 2) pushes it to the remote repository, 3) switches to master, and 4) resets master to origin/master so you can once again pull other people's work easily.